# C++ nonblocking sockets - wait for all recv data

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, send, recv

I wasn't running into this problem on my local system (of course), but now that I am setting up a virtual server, I am having some issues with a part of my code.

In order to receive all data from a nonblocking TCP recv(), I have this function

```
ssize_t Server::recvAll(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags) {
    // just showing here that they are non-blocking sockets
    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(sockfd,FIONBIO,&iMode);

   ssize_t result;
   char *pbuf = (char *)buf;
   while ( len > 0 ) {
     result = recv(sockfd,pbuf,len,flags);
     printf("\tRES: %d", result);
     if ( result <= 0 ) break;
     pbuf += result;
     len -= result;
   }

   return result;
}
```

I noticed that `recvAll` will *usually* print `RES: 1024` (1024 being the amount of bytes I'm sending) and it works great. But less frequently, there is data loss and it prints only `RES: 400` (where 400 is some number greater than 0 and less than 1024) and my code does not work, as it expects all 1024 bytes.

I tried also printing `WSAGetLastError()` and also running in debug, but it looks like the program runs slow enough due to the print/debug that I don't come across this issue.

I assume this function works great for blocking sockets, but not non-blocking sockets.

Any suggestions on measurements I can take to make sure that I do receive all 1024 bytes without data loss on non-blocking sockets?

Comment: For what it's worth, by doing a regular `recv()` without waiting for all data, the issue seems to be solved. However, I foresee this being an issue in the future (which is *quite likely* why I was using `recvAll()` in the first place).

Comment: How do you know _all data_ was received. Are you looking for data of a specific byte length? Repeat to call `recv()` until the desired length is reached.

Comment: I am *always* sending 1024 bytes, that never changes

Comment: It doesn't matter one bit how many bytes you are *sending*. TCP will fragment and defragment packets at will. A send of 1024 bytes doesn't entail a recv of 1024 bytes will succeed in one go.

Comment: Well, I am looking for data of 1024 bytes, and that is how I know when I've received all the data I need. I understand it doesn't entail all 1024, I was answering @user0042.

Comment: You'll add up blocks of received data into a buffer of `1024` bytes. Each `recv()` call in a loop tells yo how many bytes were currently received. What's your problem?

Comment: The problem is that the `recvAll()` function I provided doesn't work for nonblocking sockets. The question has been answered below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use non-blocking mode then you read all data that has already arrived to the system. Once you read out all data recv returns error and reason is depending on system:

- EWOULDBLOCK (in posix system)
- WSAEWOULDBLOCK in windows sockets system

Once you receive this error you need to wait arrival of another data. You can do it in several ways:

- Wait with special function like select/poll/epoll
- Sleep some time and try to recv again (user-space polling)

If you need to reduce delay select/poll/epoll is preferable. Sleep is much more simple to implement.

Also you need consider that TCP is stream protocol and does NOT keep framing. This means that you can send, for example, 256 bytes then another 256 bytes but receive 512 bytes at once. This also true in opposite way: you may send 512 bytes at once and receive 256 bytes with first read and another 256 bytes in next read.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, `recv()` error returns `..WOULDBLOCK` once all data has been received? I.E when I get the remaining 624 bytes from a previous 400 byte recv (totaling 1024)?

Comment: Nan, `recv` will return -1 and set `errno` to `..WOULDBLOCK`

Comment: recv returns -1 and  EWOULDBLOCK is returned by errno or by WSAGetLastError once you have read all received data. To get another 624 bytes you need to wait data arrival. This wait can be performed by sleep/poll/epoll/select/WaitForMultipleObject etc.

Comment: Or, you know, just use *blocking* sockets like Berkeley gods intended.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
@n.m. for what I'm doing (which is irrelevant to the question), I cannot do that.